# Hierarchical Deterministic (HD) Importing Funds

Tags: private-key, private-key-import, deterministic-wallets, wallet-import-format

I'm creating derived `addresses` from a `HD private key`.

I have all data saved, such as the; `seed`, `HD private key` and derived `addresses` with their `private keys`, plus `wif` formats.

I'm receiving funds in each address, but need a way to import all the funds as efficiently as possible into a SPV wallet. At the moment I import each address `wif` to recieve its corresponding balance.

Is there a neat way to pull in all funds that derive from a "master key". Or, have I misunderstood deterministic benefits - am I trying achieve a non existent feature?

**TLDR;** what's the best way to import funds from multiple addresses?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a neat way to pull in all funds that derive from a "master key". Or, have I misunderstood deterministic benefits - am I trying achieve a non existent feature?

If you import your master key (which may be in the form of a mnemonic or an `xprv`...), any BIP44 compliant wallet should be able to locate all the funds, provided you followed BIP44 when generating and using addresses.

If not, then you will have to import each key individually.